# How to count documents returned by Node-MongoDB-native stream()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream

When I [stream()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#stream) documents in the [NodeJS MongoDB native driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/), how do I determine the total number of documents that will be returned? Useful for reporting query progress, for example.

```
var stream = collection.find(query, fields, options).stream()
    .on("data", onData)
    .on("end", onEnd)
    .on("error", onError);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calling collection.count first.

```
collection.count(function(err, total) {
  var count = 0;
  var progress = 0;
  function onData() {
    progress = (++count / total) * 100;
  }

  var stream = collection.find(query, fields, options).stream()
    .on("data", onData)
    .on("end", onEnd)
    .on("error", onError);
});
```

Comment: hm. given that the collection is well-indexed for the query, count() shouldn't incur much overhead (even for queries with many many documents).  correct?

Comment: Cannot really speak to performance of Mongo but there are performance improvements that can certainly be included. For example, you can track the count between queries and only call collection.count if you have inserted a new document since the last query. Other than that just experiment a bit to see what sort of hit you are taking by counting each time.